# Geometry nodes: get line's point global coordinates

Tags: geometry-nodes, coordinates, point-clouds, lines

Somebody, help me please.
I want to bend the curve at any point. So I separate it into two parts and than I try to rotate one around the point of separation. But I cannot get the correct coordinates of the point - I get origin. So, how can I get global coordinates of any point on the line?

Also, perhaps there is a way to bend the line without splitting it? (but the question above is still relevant)
[image]

Comment: just a hint: providing a blend file would attract way more people...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all wrong.

Your *vector rotate* 'center' is still set to [0,0,0] despite the whole instance thing that you're doing.

#### Explanation

The reason why this is not working is because any data that isn't connected to the same geometry line is automatically set to 0 since it doesn't exist. even though you are capturing the instance position, the geometry isn't connected (to the set position, so it doesn't exist. You would have to sample the data with one of GN sample nodes (like *sample index*).

#### Solution

In truth there is a much simpler way of doing this. and the only operation node (the green nodes) will be a set position.

- use the *field at index* node to get the center position to rotate around. (set to *vector*, and the *position* as the *value*)
- use a compare node (set to *Integer*) with the index as *A* and the Integer value you used for the *field at index* as *B*. - this will be the selection of your set position.
- rotate the position around the vector you got from the *field at index* node, and set the position to that (with a set position node).

This only works for a single curve, but you can make some changes to make it work for multiple.
Here are the nodes:
[image]

This is an example of it working multiple curves:
[image: image being uploaded soon]

#### Alternative Solution

you can use a *sample curve* node (set to *factor* or *length*, it will just change the effect a bit), a *spline parameter* node, a *compare* node,(an *index* node, an *interpolate domain* node,) and a set position node.

sample curve node:

- the curves input of the sample curve node should be your curve.
- the index should be the index on the spline domain (so index -> interpolate domain set to *spline*).
- the factor/ length input should be a value we'll call ***F***.

compare node:

- set to *float*
- input *A* should be the *spline parameter* *factor* of *length* depending on what you set the *sample curve* to.
- input *B* should be the value ***F** we specified earlier.

set position node:

- *geometry* input should be your curve.
- selection should be the output of the *selection* node.
- the *position* input should be the *position* rotated around the *position* output of the *sample curve* node.

[image: image coming soon]
or
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it is very helpful. Sorry for the long delay in responding.